# If value of form field is less than variable show alert with info

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to do something like this: if value of this form field: 
`$('#id_erinnerung_am')`

is < `enddate` ->show `alert("Wrong");`

Java script code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_laufzeit_bis').datepicker().on('changeDate', recalculate_deadline);
    $('#id_kuendigungsfrist').change(recalculate_deadline);
    $('#id_kuendigungsfrist_type').change(recalculate_deadline);

    $('#id_kuendigung_moeglichbis').change(check_reminder_date);
    $('#id_erinnerung_am').datepicker('hide').on(check_reminder_date);

});
```

Full code: http://tnij.com/u50dt

Answer (score 1):

```
var id_erinnerung_am = $('#id_erinnerung_am').val();
if (id_erinnerung_am < enddate) {
  alert("Wrong");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have extracted the value of `#id_erinnerung_am` already to a variable of type `date` which is called `reminder_date`. And `enddate` is also a variable of type `date` (depending on what the `moment()` method does ... there is no `moment()` method in your code! So why don't you just compare them like everywhere in your code?

```
if(reminder_date < enddate) {
   alert('Wrong');
}
```

Comment: I need check this condition always if `#id_erinnerung_am` field is changed

Answer (score 0):

There's info missing but my guess from your code would be something like:

```
$('#id_erinnerung_am').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(date){
    if (date < endDate) alert('Wrong');
});
```

Comment: What is `function(date)` ?

Comment: it's an anonymous function that takes one argument. I'm supposing the changeDate event sends the new date as its first argument.

Comment: It's called `onSelect` rather than `changeDate` for the jQuery UI datepicker. But the OP failed to mention which datepicker he/she is using. And the `date` parameter will be a String, which you need to convert to a date in order to compare with another date.